# Is there a way to search for multiple users?

Tags: support

The search function seems to have a limit of one specified user.  Say that I want to find a question where I recall that two particular users were posters (say one posted the question, the other was among the answerers).  Simply including both users in the search criteria yields a list containing all posts by the second user.

Is there a way to search for posts associated with multiple users?  Couldn't find anything in the advanced search help.